# printing error for an empty input

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do a calculator app for android where i take two inputs for 2 numbers and output the result along with the function it does(i.e. addition or subtraction...).

```
public void Add(View view)
{
    float a=0,b=0,res=0;
    EditText num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView function = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    a=Float.parseFloat(num1.getText().toString());
    b=Float.parseFloat(num2.getText().toString());
    String str1 = Float.toString(a);
    String str2 = Float.toString(b);
    if(str1=="")
    {
        function.setText("Enter both Numbers");
        ans.setText("");
        return;
    }
    if(str2=="")
    {
        function.setText("Enter both Numbers");
        ans.setText("");
        return; 
    }
    res=a+b;
    String str = Float.toString(res);
    function.setText("addition");
    ans.setText(str);
}
```

so this is what i am doing. i take 2 inputs. convert them to float variables a and b. now my issue is if the user did not input an input and try for the solution, then i must produce some error saying 'enter both the numbers'. on doing it as above it's not working.

nor does it works in this manner

```
if(str1=='\0')
{
    function.setText("Enter both Numbers");
    ans.setText("");
    return;
}
```

this produces error when the input is zero.

So please help how to identify if there is no input given and to produce the error at that time.

Comment: Each time you use `==` instead of `equals`, god kills a dinosaur.

Comment: please give stack trace
that helps to suggest solution
i this Float.parseFloat(num1.getText().toString()) gives NumberFormatException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the test before converting to Float.

Your test need to be some thing like this:

```
 if (num1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
    // show error
 }
```

Comment: it gives that 'the method trim() is undefined for the type Editable'

Comment: @vinayawsm how about now?

Comment: its working fine. but what could be the problem in using try catch methods(throwing exceptions)?

Comment: @Babibu this also gives when num1 is null or contains character

Comment: @DarshanPatel If num1 is null we want an exception to be thrawn and the application to crush, this way we know we have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if(str1==null || str1.trim().equals(""))
```